# Argument not passing to particular function!

Tags: php, function, twitter

I have this

```
function twitter_tweets_per_day($user, $rounding = 1) {
    // Helper function to calculate an average count of tweets per day
    $days_on_twitter = (time() - strtotime($user->created_at)) / 86400;
    return round($user->statuses_count / $days_on_twitter, $rounding);
}

function theme_user_header($user) {
    $following = friendship($user->screen_name);
    $tweets_per_day = twitter_tweets_per_day($user, 1);
        if (($tweets_per_day) = 1) 
        {$out = Newbie;} 
        return out;
}
```

The above works flawlessly. But, this, below, doesn't work! Why? Help!

```
function twitter_mrank_page($user){
    $tweets_per_day = twitter_tweets_per_day($user, 1);
    if($tweets_per_day >= 0 && $tweets_per_day < 200){
        $out =  "'Addict'";
    }
    else{
        $out = "xxx"
    }

    $status = 'My Rank is '.$out.'! '.$tweets_per_day.' ';
    return $status;
}
```

It returns 0. Why do the first two codes work, whereas the 3rd (which comes beneath the first two in my code) doesn't?

Comment: What does `print $tweets_per_day` give you. Put it above your `if` statement in your `twitter_mrank_page` function. Also, this may be a copy/paste error, but you're not closing your `if` statement.

Comment: I assume you didn't forget to close (`}`) the `function twitter_mrank_page`

Comment: @wanovak print_r gives 1
@kongr45pen I closed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only return $status if `$tweets_per_data >= 4 && $tweets_per_day < 60`

Everything else will be 0 ... because you don't return anything

Another good point made ... you are missing a `}` to close out your function ...

1. Add debug code
2. Make sure syntax is correct

**Edit**

After updates by the Question Author, the only other suggestion I have is to ADD DEBUG CODE

Comment: Yes but if the condition is met it still returns zero. My code has conditions set for 0-200 && 200>. They all return 0.

Comment: well ... posting partial code, and not all of it may not help us to help you properly ... ?